# MediaTek Preloader USB VCOM (android) keep disconnecting

Tags: windows-10, usb, android, flash, firmware

Need help with this issue. After installing this driver and ready to flash phone the connection of usb keep disconnecting thus preventing me from flashing. I'm using latest windows 10 anniversary update. Help please!

Comment: already reinstall the drivers to the latest

Comment: my android phone being attack by viruses and Trojan that hard to remove no anti virus or rooting can make it better so flashing to original firmware is the only solution. The virus keep dialing WIFI and download porn to the phone.

Comment: I believe this is normal. My phone was also disconnecting and reconnecting (Windows 7), but SP Flash Tool was able to flash it normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out this myself accidentally and hope it help others. The problem arise from the ROM itself. So no matter what you do to connect the phone it will disconnect itself and making impossible for you to flash.

WARNING!!! ***Follow at your own risk and take it as a last resort.***

What you need to do is simple but dangerous. Instead of check "Download Only" option in SP Flash Tools Check "Download Only + Flash". What you doing here is you brick the phone in order to flash it. Sound crazy right! But this option will wipe out all error in rom so you will be able to flash it later.

Now the phone is brick :(, when you put the battery back the phone wont even start to boot. Just blank screen. You also cannot charge the phone. Remove the battery and try connect it again this time check "Download Only" in SP Flash Tools. This will install back fresh ROM and also flash the phone. Wait the flashing phone. Disconnect and voilà!

Congratulations!!! You just flash your phone :). Pat at your own back cause this is also a method to revive the dead/brick android phone.

I search everywhere including forum and all for days but no avail. Lots of suggestion but no solution. So its really easy solution now I'm enjoying my Lenovo S920 with original firmware just like newly bought android. Remember this is not a complete guide and only as reference.

***CAUTION*** ****AGAIN USE AT YOUR OWN RISK!!!****

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem with disconnecting. Phone was turned off - when I connected to PC, I heard connecting sound - also see usb drivers - but only for 2 seconds, after that, disconnecting sound and nothing.

In flashing tool (smart phone flash tool (SP flash tool)) for my elephone P9000 also didn't see that phone.

**Resolution is pretty simple:**

1. **disconnect** your turned off phone from PC
2. prepare ALL in that flashing tool (choose the *android_scatter* from image and *download agent* from flashing tool folder)
3. **CLICK** on download (I really don't know, why it's 'download'..)
4. **AFTER all of that** just connect your phone and flashing will automatically start and success! :) (after that, it will disconnect again)